# Primefaces & Spring webflow ajax action call

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, spring-webflow

Are there any way to call spring webflow action at primefaces in p:selectOneMenu?

There are two dependent combobox like as primefaces example.([link](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pprSelect.jsf)) But i want to call action which is defined at webflow transtion therefore i could not use p:ajax with actionlistener.

After search,i tried to use p:remoteCommand to call action.It execute action when parent combo change,but it also give captcha validation error (captcha at same form),therefore i set process="@this" to p:remoteCommand, when i set that i could not execute action.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using remoteCommand to invoke SWF action. If you only want to submit a value for some components you can use process="componentIds" to send only the values of specified components. You may also want 'immediate=true' on the remoteCommand to skip JSF validation - this should stop error messages from captcha validation.

However, in my experience its not a good idea to use SWF actions for tasks like refreshing dependent comboboxes. Primefaces partial rendering is much better suited for this, and does not require gimmicks like SWF  tags.

Please post your XML if immediate=true does not work.